# Can a function return more than one value?

Tags: c++, return-value

Can a function return more than one value directly (i.e., without returning in parameters taken by-reference)?

Comment: In case you want a language-agnostic overview, here's a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468375/how-do-you-return-two-values-from-a-single-method

Comment: You can return as an array or you can pass an array as a reference and store these values into that array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, but you can return a `pair` or `boost::tuple` which can contain multiple values.

In addition, you can use references to return multiple values like this:

```
void MyFunction(int a, int b, int& sum, int& difference);
```

You would call this function like this:

```
int result_sum;
int result_difference;
MyFunction(1, 2, result_sum, result_difference);
```

As Hogan points out, technically this isn't *returning* multiple variables, however it is a good substitute.

Comment: Nit pick: "In addition, you can return multiple values like this:" should be "In addition, you can modify multiple values like this:".  You can also modify globally scoped variables.

Answer (score 24):

In the `boost::tuple` library, there's [a function called `tie`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#tiers) that simplifies the process of getting information out of a returned `tuple`.  If you had a function that returned a `tuple` of two `double`s and wanted to load those into two local variables `x` and `y`, you could assign your function's return value to `boost::tie(x, y)`.

Example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

const double PI = 3.14159265;

boost::tuple<double, double> polar_to_rectangular(double radius, double angle)
{
    return boost::make_tuple(radius * cos(angle), radius * sin(angle));
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    double y;

    boost::tie(x, y) = polar_to_rectangular(4, (45 * PI) / 180);
    std::cout << "x == " << x << ", y == " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I tried to use `boost::tuple`, it gave me error `fatal error: boost/tuple/tuple.hpp: No such file or directory`, it's not part of some [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header)? I am running my program on ubuntu16.04 with command `g++ -std=c++11 swap.cpp -o main`. if I don't use `boost::tuple`, my program runs fine! Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

Yes - have your function return a struct. Or return the values via reference parameters.

```
struct A {
   int x, y;
   A(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

A myfun() {
   return A(0, 42);    // return  two values
}
```

or:

```
void myfun(int & a, int & b) {
   a = 0;
   b = 42;
}
```

Comment: Though technically that's still one value in C

Comment: Is this answering the question, "Can a function modify more than one value?"  It can also modify globals if you want to be complete.

Comment: but still only one value(its address) has been sent and we can access the whole object by copying it into another object.
i want to know specifically whether we can assign two values simultaneously.

Comment: @ashish No addresses involved. But to answer your second question, no you can't.

Answer (score 1):

A function can return values in the specified ways:

- Via return value of any type
- Via a pointer
- Via a reference
- Via setting a global variable (highly not recommended)

If you need a self contained return value, you would typically wrap the types you need in a struct and return an object of that struct by value.  If you want to avoid keeping a local copy you would pass in a reference parameter to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}Mystruct;

Mystruct myfun(); 

int main()
{
    char name[30];
    Mystruct ms2;
    ms2 = myfun();
    printf("val1: %d   val2: %d",ms2.a,ms2.b);
    return 0;
}

Mystruct myfun()
{
    int a,b;
    Mystruct ms;

    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    ms.a=a;
    ms.b=b;

    return(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use structure and return multiple value with different data type.

Answer (score -4):

```
main()
{
  int a=10,b=20;
  int *c;
  c=aa(a,b);
  printf("%d %d",*c,*c+1);
}

void aa(int a,int b)
{
   int c1[2];
   c1[0]=b+a;
   c1[1]=a-b;
   return(c1);
}
```

here, the address of c1 will be return. so it will store in main c cariable. we can retrive both variable via pointer,

Comment: Leads to undefined behavior. `c1`'s lifetime ends when `aa` is left, so `c` is left pointing at a dead object. Accessing it leads to undefined behavior.