# Can a function return more than 1 variable/structure/vector?

Tags: c++

I am writing a function in which I am passing 3 vectors of different (struct)datatypes 1 vector will contains some values and after performing all the operations I am filling other two vectors with different sets of data. So my question is Is it possible that function returns more than 1 variable/struct/vectors.

eg..

```
func_name(vect1,&vect2,&vect3) //function definition
{
// steps of performing some operations 
// enter code here vect1 contains data, vect2 & vect3 are empty
// after performing operation vect2 & vect3 filled with different set of data

is it possible to return vect2 & vect3 simultaneously.
}

func_name(vect1,vect2,vect3) // function calling.
```

Comment: No. You can return `tuple`s or `pair`s.

Comment: you pass vect2/vect3 by reference already, you don't need to return again

Comment: You should at the very least make the function parameter list something legal. It would clarify if you are passing some of the parameters by reference, for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a C++ function return more than one value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394741/can-a-c-function-return-more-than-one-value)

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable comment now my doubt is after calling of above function can I pass vect2 & vect3 to any other functions easily.

Comment: @perladdiction, yes you can pass `vect2` and `vect3` to an other function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

Answer (score 2):

Use [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29)

```
template<typename T>
void func_name(std::vector<T>& vect1,  
               std::vector<T>& vect2,
               std::vector<T>& vect3)  //..Notice & sign
{
/* Your Processing */
}

func_name(vect1,vect2,vect3);
//Now all vect1, vect2 and vect3 will be updated as per func_name processing
```

Can use `const std::vector<T>& vect1` as first argument if you don't have to update `vect1`

Comment: Thanks P0W, my vect1 is already filled with data. vect2 & vect3 are empty initially after processing on vect1 data got splitted into 2 parts and filled into vect2 & vect3. Now I can easily use vect2 & vect3 for different processings.

Comment: No, don't use references: if you call `func_name(vec1, vec2, vec3)` you should not have to expect the vectors to change. This is a bad source for bugs. By all means use pointers: `func_name(&vec1, &vec2, &vec3)` clearly says: "I'm passing the addresses of the vectors, so the vectors might be changed by the function."

Comment: Either way, output arguments are counter-intuitive and are discouraged as less readable. It's better to use well defined return value as a composite object.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this is a deficiency of most high level languages, there is no restriction like this on the assembler level. I believe the main reason for it is the way we use the return values of functions in expressions.

In my eyes, there are two usable solutions: returning structs/tuples, or passing pointers to return parameters.

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b, c;
} MyReturnType;

MyReturnType structFunc(...) {
    return (MyReturnType){
        .a = ...,
        .b = ...,
        .c = ...
    };
}

//somewhere else
    structFunc(...).c
```

Or, using pointers:

```
void pointerFunc(int* outA, int* outB, int* outC) {
    *outA = ...;
    *outB = ...;
    *outC = ...;
}

//somewhere else
    int a, b, c;
    pointerFunc(&a, &b, &c);
```

I generally prefer the pointer approach because the function declaration stands on its own. However, the structure approach has it's value as well as it reduces the clutter on the calling side if only one return value is actually used.