# Can i make a function return more than one type?

Tags: c++, oop

how to make a function return multiple types  ?
i want to make a function called view that return  view Name, ID and salary
can i make a single one (get) function to do so ?

Comment: Please don't let the down votes and inevitable closing of your question be an indicator that everyone here on SO is as hostile to new users.  Though, a quick Google or search would have answered your question.  That is why they are doing this.

Comment: There are [at least](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6394741/2615940) three [different](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2571831/2615940) questions [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/321068/2615940) that deal with multiple returns from C++ functions. If none of them answer your question, then you need to clearly explain why your question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard class `std::tuple`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::string, int, float> f()
{
    return std::make_tuple( "Doxim", 1, 3500.00 );
}

int main()
{
    auto t = f();

    std::cout << std::get<0>( t ) << '\t'
              << std::get<1>( t ) << '\t'
              << std::get<2>( t ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Doxim   1   3500
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::string, int, float> f()
{
    return std::make_tuple( "Doxim", 1, 3500.00 );
}

enum { NAME, ID, SALARY };

int main()
{
    auto t = f();

    std::cout << std::get<NAME>( t ) << '\t'
              << std::get<ID>( t ) << '\t'
              << std::get<SALARY>( t ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return a struct or a `std::tuple`.

Something like:

```
struct foo
{
    std::string Name;
    unsingned int ID;
    unsigned int salary;
};

foo bar()
{
    return {"Smith", 42, 1000};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function return a structure containing those attributes.

```
struct Foo
{
 int value1;
 int value2;
};

Foo SomeFunction()
{
Foo f = { 1, 2 };
return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :

Either use in-out parameters or create a structure/class containing all the types you need.